# Widget with autocomplete TextView

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-widget, widget, textview

i want to create a widget that when clicked on to open a dialog with a autocompletetextview(FROM THE main.class) and execute functions from mainclass.. here is my widget class and please tell me what to put in android manifest also. thx

```
 public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
 {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent)
{
    if(intent.getAction()==null)
    {
        ctxt.startService(new Intent(ctxt,ToggleService.class));
    }
    else
    {
        super.onReceive(ctxt, intent);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int [] appWidgetIds)
{
    context.startService(new Intent(context,ToggleService.class));
    //RemoteViews buildUpdate(context);
}

public static class ToggleService extends IntentService
    {
    public ToggleService() {
        super("AppWidget$ToggleService");

        }



@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    ComponentName me = new ComponentName(this,AppWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager mgr= AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    mgr.updateAppWidget(me,buildUpdate(this));
}

private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context)
{
    RemoteViews updateViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);


    Intent i=new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);
    PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i,0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.phoneState,pi);
    return updateViews;
}
```

}
}

widgetxml//

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 

     android:id="@+id/phoneState"

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

// and widget_provider.xml in res/xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:minWidth="79px"
    android:minHeight="79px"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget">


<TextView

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading..." />
```

// and part from my manifest

```
   <receiver android:name=".AppWidget"
        android:label="Caller"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider"
            />

    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".AppWidget$ToggleService"  />
```

Comment: your title is so long ...Dont use keyword like "anyone can referm me to some example how should i do it"

Comment: hi Tony this is imran. you want to start an Service or Activity?

Comment: when i press the widget i want to use my autocompletetextview (which searches contacts and when on click calls them) so anyway that is possible when click on widget to show an autocomplete( because an autocomplete..cant be a widget) and help me execute the commands that autocomplete in Main.class executes...thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upadte your manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".AppWidget"
        android:label="Caller"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
 <action android:name="com.app.example.MyWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK_RECEIVER"/>

        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider"
            />

    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".AppWidget$ToggleService"  />
```

and Update your `AppWidgetProvider`:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
        public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

        public static int appid[];
        public static RemoteViews rview;
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, 
                int[] appWidgetIds){
            updateWidgetState(context, ""); 
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
          {
             String str = paramIntent.getAction();
            if (paramIntent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK_RECEIVER)) {
                updateWidgetState(paramContext, str);   
            }
            else
            {
                    if ("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED".equals(str))
                      {
                        int i = paramIntent.getExtras().getInt("appWidgetId", 0);
                        if (i == 0)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int[] arrayOfInt = new int[1];
                            arrayOfInt[0] = i;
                            onDeleted(paramContext, arrayOfInt);
                        }
                      }
              super.onReceive(paramContext, paramIntent);
            }
          }
         static void updateWidgetState(Context paramContext, String paramString)
          {
            RemoteViews localRemoteViews = buildUpdate(paramContext, paramString);
            ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(paramContext, MyWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext).updateAppWidget(localComponentName, localRemoteViews);
          }
         private static RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context paramContext, String paramString)
          {
            // Toast.makeText(paramContext, "buildUpdate() ::"+paramString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            rview = new RemoteViews(paramContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            Intent active = new Intent(paramContext, MyWidget.class);
            active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
            active.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button 1");
            PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(paramContext, 0, active, 0);
            rmViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonus1, configPendingIntent);
            if(parmString.equals(ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK_RECEIVER))
            {

               //open a dialog with a autocompletetextview
             //your code for update and what you want on button click

            }  
             return rview; 
          }
        @Override
        public void onEnabled(Context context){
            super.onEnabled(context);
           // Toast.makeText(context, "onEnabled()  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Called each time an instance of the App Widget is removed from the host
        @Override
        public void onDeleted(Context context, int [] appWidgetId){
            super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetId);
           // Toast.makeText(context, "onDeleted()  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Called when last instance of App Widget is deleted from the App Widget host.
        @Override
        public void onDisabled(Context context) {
            super.onDisabled(context);
           // Toast.makeText(context, "onDisabled()  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: but tony yesterday as i told you dialogbox  not imposable  open from widget click.

Comment: because my pgk name is dd.caller in the manifest I should write 
<action android:name="dd.caller.MyWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK_RECEIVER"/>??

Comment: i just need the code in the AppWidgetProvider to open a dialog box and i will write all down in the dialog box, and if the dialog box is an activity with transparent bg nevermind  just how to open through the widget

Comment: <action android:name="dd.caller.YOUR_WIDGET_NAME.ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK_RECEIVER"/>

Comment: i've decidet to do this i am making new activity caller2.class and just can u show me how when pressed widget to call caller2.class(which is transparent) instead od CallerActivity.class

Comment: ok first check widget cleck happen by showing a toast within this lines `if(parmString.equals(ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK_RECEIVER))
            {

               //open a dialog with a autocompletetextview
             //your code for update and what you want on button click

            }`

Comment: replace `R.id.buttonus1` with your layout id or any control id on which click you want to open new activity